# More specific Pandas testing for equality between two dataframes

Tags: python, pandas

I want to know how the value looks in df1, and how the value looks in df2, when the two dfs fail equality tests.

This is the most specific output I could get:

```py
# more specific cell by cell test
Assertion_df = Output_Test_Cases_df.merge(Correct_Test_Cases_df).eq(Output_Test_Cases_df)
print(Assertion_df.iloc[:, [1, 2, 3]])
```

```
    DBN  AI Code  Active AI
0  True     True       True
1  False    True       True
2  True     True       True
3  True     True       True
4  True     False      True
5  True     True       True
6  True     True       True
7  True     True       True
```

However, I would like something like

```
    DBN                          AI Code                     Active AI
0  True                          True                        True
1  12X000 in df1, 12X111 in df 2 True                        True
2  True                          True                        True
3  True                          True                        True
4  True                          100 in df1, 200 in df2      True
5  True                          True                        True
6  True                          True                        True
7  True                          True                        True
```

Anything functionally equivalent to the above would be appreciated.

Comment: Provide your input data as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try something like

```
dfBool = (Correct_Test_Cases_df != Output_Test_Cases_df).stack()  # Create Frame of comparison booleans
dfDiff = pd.concat([Correct_Test_Cases_df.stack()[dfBool],
                    Output_Test_Cases_df.stack()[dfBool]], axis=1)
dfDiff.columns=["Old", "New"]
print(dfDiff)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can write your own function, after using `mask` to select only the unequal cells. I'd use this just for visualization, it's far easier to deal with individual values with just `df1.mask(s)`

#### Code:

```
def my_agg(x):
    if x.isnull().all():
        return True
    else:
        return list(zip(x, x.index.get_level_values(0)))

s = df1 == df2

(pd.concat([df1.mask(s), df2.mask(s)], keys=['df1', 'df2'])
   .groupby(level=1).agg(my_agg))

#                      A                     B                         C
#0                  True                  True                      True
#1                  True                  True                      True
#2  [(c, df1), (b, df2)]                  True  [(3.0, df1), (1.0, df2)]
#3                  True                  True                      True
#4                  True  [(E, df1), (X, df2)]                      True
```

#### Sample Data:

```
import pandas as pd
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'A': list('abcde'), 
                    'B': list('ABCDE'),
                    'C': [1,2,3,4,5]})

df2 = pd.DataFrame({'A': list('abbde'), 
                    'B': list('ABCDX'),
                    'C': [1,2,1,4,5]})
```